# List scroller with "left and right" buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I use left and right buttons on a list to scroll the content horizontally? I don't need to display a scrollbar.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none; 
  text-align: center;  
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto; 
  padding: 10px;
}

li {
  position: relative; 
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 150px;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul li img { 
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;  
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;  
  border-left: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;
  transition: box-shadow 0.1s;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>
  <img src="CSS/Imagens/diluente/diluente.png" style="border-bottom: lightgrey 1px solid;" >
  <div class="descricao_img2">Dica 1</div> 
 </li>
</ul>
```

I've already googled and tried a lot of scripts, but couldn't solve the "problem".

Answer (score 0):

Just try this hope it's useful:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul li div {
  float: right;
  width: 48%;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 150px;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul li img {
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-left: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;
  transition: box-shadow 0.1s;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="CSS/Imagens/diluente/diluente.png" style="border-bottom: lightgrey 1px solid;">
    <div class="descricao_img2">Dica 1</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```